# How to provide key for openssl decrypt in python from a variable

Tags: python, encryption, openssl

I am working on a simple brute force for encryption.  The brute force attack is trivial, but I am struggling with getting the needed value into openssl with python.  To avoid giving the answer to others doing the lab or looking for bad purposes I am only going to post my code relevant to providing the key, but it is the code that gives me the problems.

This is what I have so far.

```
os.system("openssl des-cbc -in testfile.txt -out testfile.enc -K 0x1122334455667788 -iv 0x1111111111111111") 
for x in range (0,100):
    ...
    argument = "openssl des-cbc -d -in testfile.enc -out testfile.txt -K {0} -iv 0x1111111111111111".format(hex(key))
    print argument
    os.system(argument)
    #add code here to check if the decrypt was successfull

    #increment values for next decryption
    key = key + 0x0000000000000001
    x = x + 1  
    ...
```

I have tried with and without the 0x for the hex values and also with and without the hex wrapper on the key.  By the way I am using python 2.7 so the .format should be fine and when I use print statements it seems to be to get the value into the string.

This is the error message that I am getting.

non-hex digit
invalid hex iv value

This is what I get from the print statement.  Which makes me wonder if it might be truncating in the storage of the value and that might be my problem.

openssl des-cbc -d -in testfile.enc -out testfile.txt -K 0x63 -iv 0x1111111111111111

Does anyone recognize what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Jimmy

Comment: Have you also removed the `0x` from the IV?

Comment: Yes that was part of the problem.  The other part was the truncation of the leading zeros.  I had not fixed both of those at the same time.  I have not fully fixed the issue, but it is different now.  I will post the answer I find if not one answers before then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there were two issues.  The first was the truncated zeros and is easily fixed by using the format to tell it how many zero's and to use hex.  So instead of {0} it became {0:016x} and then the fact that I had tried to fix that problem by adding in the 0x myself was a second issue as pointed out by Artjom